# ImportError even though Python modle has been installed (using gcloud)

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, pip, gcloud

I want to run a Python script via the `gcloud` command (in an Ubuntu Linux environment). That scripts needs the `hSpy` module installed:

```
$ python -m pip install hSpy
Requirement already satisfied: hSpy in /home/mfb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Django==1.3 in /home/mfb/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from hSpy)
```

However, when I run the script via `gcloud` I get the following error:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine local train --job-dir $JOB_DIR --module-name mnist_google.mnist_mlp_google_ml --package-path ./mnist_google -- --train-file ./data/mnist.pkl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/mnt/Python/KerasTutorial/mnist_google/mnist_mlp_google_ml.py", line 15, in <module>
    import h5py    # for saving the model
ImportError: No module named h5py
```

Any ideas how I can make the gcloud environment finding that `hSpy` Python module?
Do I **have to** install it globally?

**Edit**:
As mentioned in the comments, I confused packages `hSpy` and `h5py`.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you aware that your install code is installing `hSpy` but your importerror is looking for `h5py`?

Comment: As @samwalton said, [hSpy](https://pypi.org/project/hspy/) and [h5py](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/) are very different. By context, I suggest you run `pip install h5py` instead.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much guys :)

Comment: @Mangu, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @A.Queue Alright buddy :) Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As prompted previously, your `ImportError` is for [`h5py`](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/), not [`hSpy`](https://pypi.org/project/hspy/), which is what you installed before.

I suggest you run `pip install h5py` to solve this error.